# curl post picture multipart/form-data, php cURL need help!

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm trying to upload a picture to a specific website using php cURL but I don't really understand what parameters do I need to send because the data looks a bit weird . Here is what i got with the http analyzer 

`Type : multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------182983931283

-----------------------------182983931283
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Blue hills.jpg"

Content-Type: image/jpeg`

Here appears the souce of the image itself like "ÿØÿàÿØÿàÿØÿàÿØÿàÿØÿàÿØÿà"
`-----------------------------182983931283
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"

images
-----------------------------182983931283
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="anonymous_email"`

Y
-----------------------------182983931283
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="site_id"

1
-----------------------------182983931283

and so on other parameters. The issue that I have is that I don't understand what is the boundary, where do I get it from (because it doesn't appear in the html document that generates the POST and how should I make the post . If you would give me a simple example to post the above parameters to http://example.com I will definitely get the trick . 
Currently I'm using the following function to make the post :

```
   function processPicturesPage($title, $price, $numbedrooms, $description) {        //Set the login parameters and initiate the Login process    
    $fields = array(
```

"changedImages" => "", 
"site_id" => "1", 
"posting_id" => "", 
"current_live_date" => "", 
"images_loaded" => "", 
"image_actions" => "", 
"title" => $title,

);
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value)  { 
                $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
        }
        rtrim($fields_string,'&');
        $URL = "http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/add_posting.pl";
        return $this->processCurlrequest($URL, count($fields), $fields_string);
    }

and in the processCurlrequest I have the curl options (cookies etc) and url .

Comment: Ugh, try formatting your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending multipart data, boundaries are used as separators between each field. These boundaries are automatically created by cURL and you shouldn't need to worry about them.